# How to get customer session on category pages in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-account, session

Customer details are available only on customer page and checkout page. It must be a duplicate task but can someone tell how can we retrieve customer session on category pages.

```
$context = $om->get('Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context');
$isLoggedIn = $context->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);
```

we can check is logged or not but not getting any other detail for logged in user.

Answer (score 2):

You can Set and get Customer session by using **`\Magento\Customer\Model\Session`**.

First, inject the dependency into your class's constructor:

```
protected $customerSession;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession, 
    ...
){
    ...
    $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
}
```

Then, call functions like this in your code:

```
$this->customerSession->getMyValue();
```

For example, to get customer name, call:

```
$this->customerSession->getName();
```

Comment: its not working on category page

Comment: Is customer logged in at the time when you are trying to get the data?

Answer (score 0):

You can create helper or your custom helper add following code and call these getCustomer();

```
 <?php 

   protected $_customerSession;

   protected $_customerRepositoryInterface;

   public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface 
     $customerRepositoryInterface,
    ...
  ){
   $this->_customerSession = $customerSession; 
   $this->_customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
  }

  public function getCustomerId()
  {
    //return current customer ID
    return $this->_customerSession->getId();
  }

  public function getCustomer()
  {
    //return current customer data

  return $this->_customerRepositoryInterface->getById( 
  $this->getCustomerId());

  }
```